# Maximum value for filesize limit in bsub (over lsf)

Tags: lsf

I was trying to set maximum filesize using bsub -F option. But there is no manual suggesting max value.

Can some body please help in setting maximum value for filesize limit.

Comment: There's no suggested max value because it's completely dependent on what you expect the application will create.

Answer (score 0):

As Squirrel comments, this is an application specific choice. This is an optional input and I think the idea here is to prevent a runaway job from filling up storage space. If a job exceeds this limit, LSF will be kill that job.

Quote from [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_command_ref/bsub.1.dita):

> -F file_limit
>
> Sets a per-process (soft) file size limit for each of the processes that belong to the job (see getrlimit(2)). The limit is
> specified in KB.
>
> If a job process attempts to write to a file that exceeds the file
> size limit, then that process is sent a SIGXFSZ signal. The SIGXFSZ
> signal normally terminates the process.

Comment: Actually reason I am looking for max value is because I am launching this as a child process and I have already set some limits on parent which I didn't want child to inherit.

Comment: Max file size depends on the file system and of course, on available storage space. This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305508/how-the-file-size-is-limited-on-a-specific-file-system